# Minimize compose window and run function in an Outlook web add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am currently working on a web add-in that processes, modify and then sends the email.

I'm attached to the ItemSend event: `<Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateBody" />`. This validate the body and then sends it.

The problem I have is that processing the email might take up to 40 seconds and I don't want the user to be blocked for that amount of time.

**I was wondering is there a way to minimize the compose window and still run the processing function and the close that minimized window once its done?**

I know that the add-in only works on the current item so when I send the email I can still access the other pages but once the email is trying to send itself and close the compose window nothing happens.

This is the function that sends the email:

```
async function sendInBackGround(htmlArr, message = "") {
const subject = await getEmailSubject();

const messageDiv = "<div>" + message + "</div>";

for (const htmlArrObject of htmlArr) {
    debugger;
    var request = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
    '  <soap:Header><t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" /></soap:Header>' +
    '  <soap:Body>' +
    '    <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendOnly">' +
    '      <m:Items>' +
    '        <t:Message>' +
    '          <t:Subject>' + subject.value + '</t:Subject>' +
    '             <t:Body BodyType="HTML"><![CDATA[' + htmlArrObject.html + messageDiv + ']]></t:Body>' +
    '          <t:ToRecipients>' +
    '            <t:Mailbox><t:EmailAddress>' + htmlArrObject.recipient + '</t:EmailAddress></t:Mailbox>' +
    '          </t:ToRecipients>' +
    '        </t:Message>' +
    '      </m:Items>' +
    '    </m:CreateItem>' +
    '  </soap:Body>' +
    '</soap:Envelope>';

    Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(request, (asyncResult) => {
        console.log(request);
        if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {
            console.log("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Message sent!");
            mailboxItem.close();
        }
    });
}
```

}

When I send the item and wait on the compose window for the process to be done, the asyncResult has a status and a value that are defined. But when I change windows while the process is running, for example I go on an other compose window and start writing another email, the asyncResult object has a status of succeeded but the value returned is undefined.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering is there a way to minimize the compose window and still run the processing function and the close that minimized window once its done?

No, there is no way with web-based add-ins. You can post your feature request/suggestion to the [Tech Community Page](https://to%20https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform). Don't forget to choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on `Tech Community` are considered when the team go through the planning process.

As a side note, you can implement the required functionality with COM based add-ins nowadays. For example, you may consider developing a VSTO add-in instead, see [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022) for more information.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!

Comment: Just confirming that Eugene's answer is correct (as it the link for new feature suggestions, and his suggestion about COM add-ins)